# Tableview in scrollview not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, pagination

I was trying to implement a view like twitter's iOS app. The view controller contains a scroll view can scroll horizontally, in each page of the scrollview, there is a tableview. For simplicity I just created two UITableView, and add them inside two UIView containers, because besides tableView, I also have some view to show, so the tableView and all other views are added as subViews of the viewContainer for each page.

The view hierarchy is like this:

```
UIViewController
--view
  --scrollView
    --view1
      --tableView1
      --someOtherViews
    --view2
      --tableView2
      --someOtherViews
```

In the viewDidLoad methods, I implemented something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //Some other setup...

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame(0,y0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-offset)];
    scrollView.pageEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height - offset);
    [self.view addSubView:scrollView];

    view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-offset)];
    tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-offset) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView1.delegate = self;
    tableView1.dataSource = self;
    //other setup...
    [view1 addSubView:tableView1];
    [scrollView addSubView:view1];

     view2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-offset)];
    tableView2 = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-offset) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView2.delegate = self;
    tableView2.dataSource = self;
    //other setup...
    [view2 addSubView:tableView2];
    [scrollView addSubView:view2];
}
```

For test purpose, I populate the same datasource for both tables. The problem is if I only add one tableView container (for instance view1, which includes tableView1) as the subView of the scrollView, the view shows perfect, one can page to second page, which is blank, and the view controller can be load and show. The same for the second one.

However, if I use the code above, which adds both view containers as the subView of the scrollView, the app would crash when load this view controller. However, if I add the second view container (view2 or view1), but in the view container, I am not adding tableView as its subView, but has other subViews, it works perfectly.

So I figured the problem probably comes from two tableViews. However, I have tried to debug this for a few hours, and still no luck. Anyone can help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: I doubt the `CGRect` of the `UITableView` specially this line `self.view.frame.size.height-offset` check the frame..

Comment: @iphonic Thanks! But I'm a little confused. Could you please explain more? The CGRect of the tableView is correct if I only have one tableView there. Are you suggesting when adding two tableViews, the CGRect of the second of the first actually changed?

Comment: I would suggest few things. 1. Your process is wrong, better compose a separate xib with class and design your view. 2. Manage everything there including the datasource and delegates etc, and just use the xib to add directly. There can be several reasons why its not working for you, might be datasource conflicting, or the delegates are not getting called etc..

Answer (score 0):

I think it is something with you `UITableViewDelegate` or `DataSource` methods.
Probably it is the reason you crash.

-Suggestion:

try to make your `UITableView`s as an iVar and in `dataSource` methods 
specify the tableView you want

like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView == _tableView1)
        return _table1DataSource.count;
    else
        return _table2DataSource.count;
}
```

try to do it for other methods.